# Cannot insert values into database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

trying to insert form values into database using codeigniter but nothing heppens.
my form is **comment_form.php** is like,

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('news/comment_form'); ?>

Name<input type="text" name="comment_name"></input><br />
Email<input type="text" name="comment_email"></input><br />
Comment<input type="text" name="comment_body"></input><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment it" ></input>

</form>
```

here's my controller **comments.php**

```
class Comments extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('comment_model');
    }

    public function create_comment()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');


        //$data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment_name', 'comment_name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment_email', 'comment_email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment_body', 'comment_body', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('news/comment_form');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            $this->news_model->set_comment();
            $this->load->view('news/success');
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my model **comment_model.php**

```
class Comment_model extends CI_Model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }


    public function set_comment()
    {
        //$this->load->helper('url');

        //$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

        $datac = array(
            'comment_name' => $this->input->post('comment_name'),
            'comment_email' => $this->input->post('comment_email'),
            'comment_body' => $this->input->post('comment_body')
        );

        return $this->db->insert('comments', $datac);
    }
}
```

the problem is whenever i submitting the form it returns nothing, like nothing happened.please help.

Comment: input doesn't have closing tag. Try removing and submitting again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **comment_form.php** change

```
echo form_open('news/create_comment');
```

to

```
echo form_open('comments/create_comment');
```

**Why?**  Because the first parameter you give to form_open() is the action parameter. It will open a form tag like `<form action="bla">`. And news/create_comment is not the correct page you want to call. Your controller is named `comments`, that's why you put `comments/create_comment`.

In your **comments.php** change

```
$this->news_model->set_comment();
```

to

```
$this->comment_model->set_comment();
```

**Why?** Just simply pointing to the false model. Maybe a copypaste-error?

In your **comment_model.php** remove

```
$this->load->database();
```

And load it in your **config.php** (in the libraries array, add 'database').

**Why?** IMHO this is the more proper solution. You're probably gonna use your database pretty often, so why load that everytime?

If you still encounter problems, then we need more information. What exactly is not working. Do some debugging for us. After you call `$this->news_model->set_comment()` write `var_dump($this->db->last_query());`

Answer (score 0):

In the `set_comment` function after `$this->db->insert('comments', $datac);` just echo the query using below command and try running the same query manually in the database, you may come to know the issue.

> echo $this->db->last_query();

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
$this->load->database();
echo form_open('news/comment_form');
$this->news_model->set_comment();
```

To:

```
$this->load->library('database');
echo form_open('news/create_comment');
$this->comment_model->set_comment();
```

It would be better if you load your database library in your `autoload.php`. Or in your controller's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
this->news_model->set_comment()
```

Should be

```
this->comment_model->set_comment()
```

PS: sorry for the formatting. Mobile version doesn't read new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Get the posted values in controller instead of model and then pass them to model.

Controller function

```
public function create_comment()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment_name', 'comment_name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment_email', 'comment_email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment_body', 'comment_body', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/comment_form');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        $data['comment_name']   =   $this->input->post('comment_name'),
        $data['comment_email']  =   $this->input->post('comment_email'),
        $data['comment_body']   =   $this->input->post('comment_body')

        $this->news_model->set_comment();
        $this->load->view('news/success');
    }
}
```

Model function

```
public function set_comment($data)
{
    //$this->load->helper('url');

    //$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

    $this->db->insert('comments', $data);

    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

EDITS

The above code will work if you follow these steps.

Go to `database.php` in `application/config` and provide database connection settings like `hostname` , `username` , `password` and `database` name.
Then go to `autoload.php` in `application/config` and autoload the database library like this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Also remove the closing tags for input in your html form.
Try testing like this in controller before moving forward

```
$post = $this->input->post();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($post);
```

This will ensure you are receiving post data